# how to stop objects go out of the container bounds when using move effect in flex4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, move, effects

the setup 
i have a container (tested with group, panel, bordercontainer) with size 500x100
inside the container i have 5 images 100x100 
when i apply a move effect on the images and move all of them with 100px to the right or left they just move completely ignoring the bounds of the parent container like they sit on top of it.
the move effect works ok when pictures go beyond the application borders

Answer (score 0):

manage to find a solution
put all in mx:canvas smaller than your original container
so if you want to move some staff in a container with size 500x100 create another one 499x99 and all moving objects will disappear when the move effect reach the end of the container